# What is the easiest way to programmatically obtain the current USD-BTC spot price?

Tags: development, exchanges, exchange-rate

E.g., if I wanted to create a cron script that would grab the latest spot price every hour and store it in a local file or database, what would be the place to "scrape" that information from?

(Actually writing the script is not the problem, in my case.)

Comment: FYI, I ended up using the [API of BitcoinCharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/) to do this.  The Mt Gox API may have worked just as well in my case, but for whatever reason, I was having an issue with my (Python) script that attempted to poll mtgox.com -- it would hang upon making the HTTPS request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably dozens of sites that now provide this data, but the CoinDesk API is one option.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the JSON encoded ticker data available from MtGox at: https://mtgox.com/api/0/data/ticker.php

Just use whatever your language's equivalent to [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or [wGet](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) is and parse as appropriate.

Comment: Unsurprisingly (to anyone familiar with the now-infamous Mt Gox saga), this method will no longer work.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using [www.btcrate.com](http://www.btcrate.com) as well, which supports additional currencies (should you need them).